# Application freeze after manual rotation in iOS 5

Tags: ios, rotation

So i have a bug. It appears when i try to rotate my application after user clicked unlock rotation button. For this feature i use next code

```
    RotateHelperViewController *viewController = [[RotateHelperViewController alloc] init];
    viewController.neededOrientation = currentDeviceOrientation;
    self.orientationFromLockedState = currentDeviceOrientation;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
        [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:NO];
        }
        completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [viewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
            [viewController release];
            self.orientationFromLockedState = -1;
        }];
```

this bug appears only on ios 5.x on iOS 6.x all works good. Also rotation works fine if we rotate automaticaly.

Comment: Thanks. Question was solved by using [UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation]. this will not work if we try support iOS 4.3

Answer (score 0):

Question was solved by using [UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation]. this will not work if we try support iOS 4.3